# json where clause in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, where-clause

I have save  data in PostgreSQL as given below:

```
{"tags": "Tag 1,Tag 2,Tag 3"}
{"tags": "Tag 1,Tag 4,Tag 5"}
{"tags": "Tag 6,Tag 1,Tag 2"}
```

I want search records where 'Tag 2' or Tag 3 exists?

Table schema, create procedure is as below,

```
--create table 
CREATE TABLE "tblIrsInputTagging" ( 
  "IrsInputTaggId" serial NOT NULL, 
  "Irs_tags" json NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "tblIrsInputTagging_pkey" 
  PRIMARY KEY ("IrsInputTaggId") 
) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE ); 
ALTER TABLE "tblIrsInputTagging" OWNER TO "postgre";

--insert json record 

INSERT INTO "tblIrsInputTagging" ("Irs_tags") 
VALUES ( '{"tags": "Tag 1,Tag 2,Tag 3"}' );

INSERT INTO "tblIrsInputTagging" ("Irs_tags") 
VALUES ( '{"tags": "Tag 1,Tag 4,Tag 5"}' ); 

INSERT INTO "tblIrsInputTagging" ("Irs_tags") 
VALUES ( '{"tags": "Tag 6,Tag 1,Tag 2"}' );
```

Comment: data type of column is json

Comment: are those taglists, i mean, "Tag1, Tag2, Tag3" an array, or just a text?

Comment: its just a text

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is some specific function to check per json items. But you can do so by casting the data type as text then check it with `like` or `ilike` operator.

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_name WHERE CAST(col1 AS text) ilike '%value%'
```

notice that the col1 column is the json data type.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the column name is `tags`. In that case, you can query like below.
If there is something specific, let me know, so I might need to update below snippet.

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, .. col_n 
FROM your_table 
WHERE tags::json->'tags' ILIKE '%Tag2%'
OR
tags::json->'tags' ILIKE '%Tag3%'
```

Comment: Looks like your `LIKE` pattern is missing wildcards.

Comment: ERROR:  column "Tag2" does not exist
LINE 2: WHERE "Irs_tags"::json->'tags' ILIKE "Tag2" 
                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "Tag2" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 73

Comment: Dear Laurenz Albe its showing error that column "Tag 2" doses not exist even its not  a column it is data inside the tag column of jason.

Comment: @NarenderPal please update your question body with that error message.

Comment: ERROR: column "%Tag2%" does not exist still same error

Comment: --create table
CREATE TABLE "tblIrsInputTagging"
(
  "IrsInputTaggId" serial NOT NULL,
  "Irs_tags" json NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "tblIrsInputTagging_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("IrsInputTaggId")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "tblIrsInputTagging"
  OWNER TO "postgre";


--insert json record
INSERT INTO "tblIrsInputTagging" ("Irs_tags") VALUES ( '{"tags": "Tag 1,Tag 2,Tag 3"}' );
INSERT INTO "tblIrsInputTagging" ("Irs_tags") VALUES ( '{"tags": "Tag 1,Tag 4,Tag 5"}' );
INSERT INTO "tblIrsInputTagging" ("Irs_tags") VALUES ( '{"tags": "Tag 6,Tag 1,Tag 2"}' );

Comment: I share the script of table with data please share the solution if it can be. thanks